# How to use assertions in my basic javascript calculating program?

Tags: javascript, html, exception, assertions

I am trying to implement assertions into my program (which calculates the volume of a box with dimensions inputted by user) to check expressions such as whether the user input is really a number and if it is bigger than zero. I created the function assert that takes in the expression to test and the message it needs to display if there is an error but it's not working for me. I would write the line of code that invokes the assert function like, assert( (typeof length == 'number'), 'The length must be a number'); but when I do, the program won't work at all. If I add console.assert( (typeof length == 'number'), 'The length must be a number'); , the program runs, but it doesn't do the error checking that I need it to do. I am only starting to learn how to do js exception handling so I'm not even sure if I'm implementing this right at all?

```js
function calculate(){
   'use strict';
   //declare variables used to calculate volume of the box
   var volume;
  //Bullet #4
    
    var length = document.getElementById('length').value;
    console.assert( (typeof length == 'number'), 'The length must be a number');
    console.assert( (length > 0), 'The length must be larger than 0.');
    
    var width = document.getElementById('width').value;
    console.assert( (typeof width == 'number'), 'The width must be a number');
    console.assert( (width > 0), 'The width must be larger than 0.');
    
    var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
    console.assert( (typeof height == 'number'), 'The height must be a number');
    console.assert( (height > 0), 'The height must be larger than 0.');
   
    //calculate the volume
    volume = length * width * height;
    volume = volume.toFixed(2);
    console.assert( (!isNaN(volume)), 'The volume is not a number.');
    
    //display the volume
    document.getElementById('volume').value = volume;
 
  return false;
 
}
//Bullet #4
function assert(expression, message){
 if (!expression) throw {name: 'Assertion Exception', message: message};
}

   function init(){
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = calculate;
   }
   window.onload = init;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>box calculator</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- box.html -->
    <form action="" method="post" id="theForm">
        <fieldset>
            <p>Use this form to calculate the volume of a box.</p>
   <div><label for="length">Length</label><input type="text" name="length" id="length" required></div>
   <div><label for="width">Width</label><input type="text" name="width" id="width" required></div>
   <div><label for="height">Height</label><input type="text" name="height" id="height" required></div>
   <div><label for="volume">Volume</label><input type="text" name="volume" id="volume"></div>
   <div><input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="submit"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script src="js/box.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick `console.log()` before your assertions would reveal that the type of any `DOM.value` is a string.

quick fix is to apply `Number()` to these strings (`length`, `height` and `width`) to make them numbers

Note: applying `Number()` to the strings that aren't number genererates `NaN` which has type `Number` so you need to change your assertion statements as well.
I suggest the following format for each measure:

```
var length = Number(document.getElementById('length').value);
console.assert(!isNaN(length), 'The length must be a number');    
console.assert( (length > 0), 'The length must be larger than 0.');
```